# Marshalling a pointer to a C string (char **)

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a call I want to make from C#, the C declaration is:

```c
extern void UPOS_DLL_METHOD udmRetrieveStatistics(
    udm_Handle device,
    udm_ASCIIZString *statisticsBuffer
);
```

`udm_ASCIIZString` is a typedef:

```c
typedef char *udm_ASCIIZString;
```

The called code specifically warrants that the string will not be deallocated until the next call. How do I get this done? My most recent attempt is:

```cs
[DllImport("CPOSUDMAdapter.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void udmRetrieveStatistics(int device, ref IntPtr statisticsBuffer);
```

and I call the function like so:

```cs
IntPtr dataPtr = default(IntPtr);
udmRetrieveStatistics(_printerDevice, ref dataPtr);
var data = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(dataPtr);
Console.WriteLine("data = <" + data + ">");
```

`data` is always empty.

Comment: What does `dataPtr` equal when it returns, and is `udm_Handle` an int?

Comment: It equals zero, and so I discovered the C function call is failing. It is, in turn, calling a Java function so I have a different problem to solve. Thank you.

Comment: There you go, a bit of debugging and you know what is happening.